# Pointer to function that was copied from code

Tags: c, memory-management

I am studying about memory handling and I came across this code:

```
void print(const char * str){
    printf(str);
}

void (*print_ptr)(const char *)=print;

void foo2(void){
    print("goo\n");
    return;
}

void baz(void){
    print("foo\n");
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char buf[256];
    void (*func_ptr)(void)=(void (*)(void))buf;
    memcpy(buf,foo2,((void *)baz)-((void *) foo2));
    func_ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

This code will cause seg fault reaching

```
func_ptr();
```

I cant understand why. If I change the pointer to point a static function (like `func_ptr=&baz` it will work properly, but a dynamic code will not. 
The code itself, as I understand it, will be copied to the stack, where it should be.
What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is copy the object code consisting of `foo2()` into your buffer and execute it. This won't work for a number of reasons:

1. Your code is copied to `buf` which will be allocated in data space, which is non-executable (i.e. the memory manager will not have execute permission set on that area of memory).
2. The code is unlikely to be relocatable in the general case. It may either contain absolute references to itself, or relative references to the rest of the code, both of which will break on copying.
3. You have no guarantee that the code will be compiled with the functions in the order given, so there is no guarantee you are copying just `foo2()`. In fact there is no guarantee the compiler will produce the `foo2()` as a single contiguous binary blob. Part of it might (for instance) be after `bar()`. Or (relatively common case) parts of the function might be before the entry point.

If you really want to understand why it's breaking, fix (1) by allocating the memory for `buf` with `mmap()` and `MAP_ANON`, using `PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC`, then run it under `gdb`. I'd suggest compiling with `-O0` (disable optimisation) to maximise chances of something working, but I would repeat you have no guarantees.

The larger question is why on earth you want to copy bits of your code around.

Comment: Regarding 2: You mean that if there is a call for a function, it will be translated to a relative address (i.e. an offset), so if I copy that part, when it tries to reach that offset it might reach a memory segment that it shouldn't?

Comment: @YinonEliraz, no I mean within the function, it might refer to a relative address `PC+N` which is outside the function, or to an absolute address `X` which is inside the function. Either of those can cause issues if the function is relocated.

Comment: Here we are talking about the call for the local function print ?

Comment: @YinonEliraz yes, could be, but it could be anything. You have no idea how it might (for instance) set up the internal stack frame. In general you have no guarantee how the C compiler does its job. It merely has to comply with the C standards and it could do that in the most opaque and bizarre way possible (and modern compilers when optimizing often seem to do that).

Comment: Thanks alot!! Got it!